# Rails 3.2: ActiveRecord model without i18n_key - how could it possible and how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Models example:

```
class ModelOne < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end

class ModelTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

From rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> ModelOne.model_name.i18n_key
NoMethodError: undefined method `i18n_key' for "model_one":String
[2] pry(main)> ModelTwo.model_name.i18n_key
=> :model_two
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of 3.2 are you specifically using?  For 3.2.22.2, I get what I expect eg: `User.model_name.i18n_key => :user`, but I also get `User.model_name.class => ActiveModel::Name`, while you seem to be getting a string.  Are you sure you (or some other gem you use) haven't overridden the `model_name` method?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right. Found this method in included module. def model_name
      table_name[0..-2]
end

Comment: Great! In that case, I'll put it in as an answer.

Comment: The problem is that its not my code. But I have to add validation there. I think return singular table_name in override is not right way, but I don't know why it's done and what depends on it. Can you suggest something?

Comment: I think if I was in your position, I'd look for any tests for `ModelOne.model_name` to hopefully find a reason as to _why_ it was overridden.  If there are no tests, do a search in my project to see _where_ the overridden `model_name` method is being used, see if the Rails version can substitute for it, and write tests confirming whether it can or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723485/rails-3-2-activerecord-model-without-i18n-key-how-could-it-possible-and-how-t#comment59191234_35723485), since `ModelOne.model_name` should return you an object of type `ActiveModel::Name`, rather than of `String`, the `ModelOne.model_name` method has likely been overridden.

So, you'll have to either decide to remove the override (probably better unless there is a very good reason it's there), or work around it as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've removed override of model_name and refactored all methods where it was used. Seems like all work fine.

Comment: @VictorKakhnych Great!  In that case, please consider marking this answer as accepted (click the checkmark "✓" under the score).